# Manual Deploy - How to defer deployment for later?

Tags: azure-devops

On a manual deploy of a release, is it possible to defer deployment to a later time ?

[image]

I would like the same option that is available when using a Pre-Deployment approval:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have go through the approval workflow with a manual deployment. You can use the defer option as you normally would.

Comment: The question was for Release pipeline with no pre-deployment approval

Comment: @GuillaumeMorin Add a pre-deployment approval. Create the release, then approve it and defer the release.

Comment: Ok thanks, I wanted to check if there was a simpler way.